# error during pcl_ros

Tags: pcl, rosmake, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I downloaded pcl and perception_pcl from pointclouds.org and did rosdep without any errors..

when I rosmake pcl_ros, its resulting the errors below.

mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package pcl_ros
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only pcl_ros
CMake Error at /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:16 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
Command add_executable() is not scriptable
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:231 (INCLUDE)
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/pcl17/pcl/vtk_include.cmake:1 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'pcl_ros'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55591/error-during-pcl_ros/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the one provided with ROS, type in a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pcl* ros-fuerte-perception*
```

Unless you wanted to use some unstable ones ?

Bests reguards,

Steph

Ps :And next time, don't forget to precise : your distribution (Ubuntu xx.xx), your platform, and which ROS you use (I see from the error message you are using fuerte)

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-02-19**:
ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte, The registration library which i wanted to use is not up to date in ros-fuerte repository. So I downloaded from the trunk from pcl website which has ros wrappers but it isresulting in the above errors given in the question

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-02-19**:
OK... Yes, I tried to compiled pcl trunk also but a lot of things doesn't compile in it, thus needing to flag only the part you want to compile, and leave the rest out. You can go to PCL support forum, in which you may find more help (suscribe at http://pointclouds.org/mailman/listinfo/pcl-users)